# Creating archive pages for children categories

Tags: categories, archives

**Example:**

video cat id = 4
video cat child category id's = 7,8,9
news cat id = 5
news cat child category id's = 11,12,13

I wanna display choosen categories ( like video and news ) in the different archive.php?

Is it possible thanks.

( sorry about my bad Eng )

Thanks for Chris S but its not what i want to do.

```
  <?php
$catPosts = new WP_Query();
$catPosts->query( array( 'category__and' => array(5,11,12,13), 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'DESC' ) );
  while ($catPosts->have_posts()) : $catPosts->the_post(); ?>
  <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
  <div class="meta">
   By <?php the_author() ?>
  </div>
<div class="content">
  <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
</div>
```

When I wrote the parent category id, i dont wanna write its child category id's. When i choose the parent category id the system should its child category ids in the same archive page.

Comment: Do you want your child categories on separate archive pages, or all of them to be in one?

Comment: separate archive pages... 

**example**: the news category archive ( included with child categories ) in archive-news.php

the videos category archive ( included with child categories ) in examle archive-video.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create 2 pages category-news.php & category-video.php & put this code in them. Then customize the markup for both as you like

```
<?php
$children = get_categories('child_of'=>get_query_var('cat'));
$cat = array(get_query_var('cat'));
foreach($children as $child)
    $cat[] = $child->term_id;
$catPosts = new WP_Query( array( 'category__in' => $cat, 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'DESC' ) );
  while ($catPosts->have_posts()) : $catPosts->the_post(); ?>
  <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
  <div class="meta">
   By <?php the_author() ?>
  </div>
<div class="content">
  <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

Taking a look at the **[Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy)** in WordPress could be useful. WordPress allows you to use different templates for different categories based on Category slug (`category-{slug}.php`) or Category ID (`category-{id}.php`).

As for different post types, you could do `archive-{post_type}.php`.

Essentially, you could simply copy `archive.php` and rename it to `category-{slug}.php`, `category-{id}.php` or `archive-{post_type}.php` (depending on what suits you best) and then modify the existing code in the template to your needs. Just a thought.

Comment: How does that provide a solution specifically for sub categories?

Answer (score 0):

So you already know that you need to create a archive-category.php template for each category. Within each template you would call a custom query for each of those categories and their child categories. For example:

```
<?php
$catPosts = new WP_Query();
$catPosts->query( array( 'category__in' => array(5), 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'DESC' ) );
  while ($catPosts->have_posts()) : $catPosts->the_post(); ?>
  <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
  <div class="meta">
   By <?php the_author() ?>
  </div>
<div class="content">
  <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
</div>
```

This one shows the "news" category with it's children included. Note that you can place any of your own tags to output whatever HTML you want.

Comment: Dude, when i choose a parent category id, the system should display its child category in the same archive page. I dont wanna write all child categories ids..

Comment: Sorry about that. I edited it to query "news" category and it's children in your archive.

Comment: did this work for you?

Comment: didnt work chris when i click the sub category the regular archive page came.